# How to get total for Crystal report static columns and dynamic columns on single line in bottom (Cross tab)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, crosstab

[I need to get Total of 'Static column 2' on position A and total of 'Static column 3' on position B. This time i'm using Crystal report Cross tab option on Visual studio 2015,Refer Image using this link,
Thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96IaD.png)

Comment: plz mention your crystal version

Comment: It comes with Visual studio 2015